# RMarkdown References section -name change

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I'm currently writing in R Studio an R Markdown document. Since I am not using English, I want to change the name of the # References header to "Referencias". My output is HTML.
I went thru the pandoc documentation and tried reference-section-title: Referencias in my YALM header, with no luck.

Comment: Are you using bookdown? It would also be helpful if you could post your YAML header.

Comment: I think if you set the doc's language with the YAML metadata header `language`, in newer pandoc versions, there is [a translation for that](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/translations/en.yaml)..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to set the metadata field `reference-section-title` in the YAML header:

```
---
reference-section-title: Referencias
---
```

Alternatively, you could write the section title directly into the document, then use a special fenced div with id `#refs` to place the bibliography anywhere you need it:

```
# Referencias

::: #refs
:::
```