# Change "References" by "Bibliography" in Bookdown (gitbook)

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I would like to change the name of the section "References" to something else. I am using the R Studio Bookdown template:

````
# Introduction {#intro}

You can label chapter and section titles using `{#label}` after them, e.g., we can reference Chapter \@ref(intro). If you do not manually label them, there will be automatic labels anyway, e.g., Chapter \@ref(methods).

Figures and tables with captions will be placed in `figure` and `table` environments, respectively.

```{r nice-fig, fig.cap='Here is a nice figure!', out.width='80%', fig.asp=.75, fig.align='center'}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
plot(pressure, type = 'b', pch = 19)
```

Reference a figure by its code chunk label with the `fig:` prefix, e.g., see Figure \@ref(fig:nice-fig). Similarly, you can reference tables generated from `knitr::kable()`, e.g., see Table \@ref(tab:nice-tab).

```{r nice-tab, tidy=FALSE}
knitr::kable(
  head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!',
  booktabs = TRUE
)
```

You can write citations, too. For example, we are using the **bookdown** package [@R-bookdown] in this sample book, which was built on top of R Markdown and **knitr** [@xie2015].
````

This produces a subsection called "References" at the end of the chapter. I tried to change this e.g. by adding

```
language:
  label:
    refs: 'Bibliography'
```

to the _bookdown.yml - without success. I couldn't find an answer for this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269446/rmarkdown-references-section-name-change

Comment: @user2084364 in the meantime I checked the possibility you suggested and it works. Thanks.